# Calling a Django server function from PHP server

Tags: php, django, api, django-celery, celery-task

I Just hired as a junior python developer at a company (i'm the only python developer).
Here they want to pass a heavy tasks (bulk mailing,Excel import,PDF export) from a PHP server to a django server(**celery**) to reduce work load.
In my computer I managed to run them both locally (separately).

> **My question is what is the best way to pass the data or trigger a function at django server from PHP server**

For example consider the code below :
some_shit.php

```
    public function actionExportPdf()
    {
        $mPDF = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();
        $model   = new Gulfuniversityapplication('search');
        $dbcriteria = Yii::app()->session['criteria'];
        $model->setDbCriteria($dbcriteria);

        $row  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select field_data from modules where table_name='".$model->tableName()."'")->queryRow();
        $filteredData = CJSON::decode($row['field_data']);
        //$filteredData = $data[$model->tableName()];
        $stylesheet = file_get_contents(getcwd().'/path/to/core/assets/css/social.css');
        $mPDF->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
        $mPDF->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('_exportPdf',array(
                        'model' => $model,
                        'data' => $filteredData,
                ), true));
        $mPDF->Output();
    }
```

This is their PHP I have no idea what's in it.

Here is my Django celery code 
tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def export_task(arg1,arg2):
    my_cursor = my_db.cursor()
    my_cursor.execute("SELECT arg1 FROM arg2")
    out =[]
    for i in my_cursor.fetchall():
        out.append(i)
    my_cursor.execute("DESCRIBE arg2")
    column = []
    for i in my_cursor.fetchall():
        column.append(i[0])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=out,columns=column)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```

This is my first question here thanks in advance.

> I have been thinking about POST API calls from PHP

if that's the only solution explain it for yii framework

Comment: You can connect to Celery from PHP: https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php

Comment: Do you want to say, currently these tasks(bulk mailing,Excel import,PDF export)) are processing by PHP which you want to do by Python?

Comment: yes they already doing it but it adds a huge workload @Suresh

Comment: To process those tasks(bulk mailing,Excel import,PDF export) are you making any kind of HTTP request to current PHP script or using some other method like wrote any cron job?

Comment: I guess they don't use any requests they are written in pure PHP so they said they use cron method @Suresh

Comment: If they are not using any HTTP request then, just wrote one equivalent Python script for doing all those heavy tasks(bulk mailing,Excel import,PDF export) & aattach that script with a CRON with a specific time of a day. So, everyday at that time that Python script automatically get trigger & start processing those heavy task.

Comment: Yeah that's a great idea but I want to use a seperate Django server for celery that continuously checks the cron .

Comment: Ok. You can do that one also. That will probably help you get status of all your heavy processing task from Celery.